# None value returned when trying to access variables across flask sessions

Tags: python, flask, session

```
from flask import Flask, session, request, render_template
import model   //model.py

app = Flask(_name__)
session.key = "randomkey"

@app.route("/", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        //Some cide that takes input from index.html and stores in python variables
        prediction = model.make_prediction(modelinput)
        session["prediction"] = prediction
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/prediction", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def submit():
    final_prediction = session.get("prediction", None)
    return render_template("prediction.html", predic = final_prediction)
```

Now even though I use a session variable to pass the value between the sessions, I get a None value as the output. Why is that?

Comment: I ran your code on my system, without the database and it's working fine. Check if ```prediction = model.make_prediction(modelinput)``` this line is giving the desired output or not.

Comment: Yes, that line is giving the desired output. I verified by using the print function to print the variable in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your code:

```
from flask import Flask, session, request, render_template
import model   //model.py

app = Flask(_name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "topSecret"
```